# Numpy: extract data and coordinates from 2-D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Given:

```
M = [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]]

N = [[(0,1), (1, 0)],
     [(1,1), (0,0)]]
```

With `M` and `N`, both of dimension `2x2`. How might I get a list `L`, of tuples, where each tuple is the combination of the position of the value, and the values from `M` and `N`:

```
L = [((0,0), (0,1), 1) ...]
```

Where the first entry above in `L`, is the position `(0,0)` in `M` and `N`, and  the tuple/value `(0,1)` from `N`, and the value `1` from `M`.

Do I need to stack `M`, `N` to create a third dimension? And does `numpy` have a clean and efficient way to produce such a list of tuples?

Comment: N is 3 dimensional, is this what you meant?

Comment: No, N is a 2x2 array of tuples.

Comment: Have you tried with numpy.ndenumerate ?

Comment: Yes, that makes it 3d. Try using printing  np.array(N).shape to see. In any case, why do you need the position in L? I mean it seems like saving L as an array where L[0][0]=((0,1),1) would be nicer instead of saving the indices.

Comment: The elements in `L` just map the index to the values. That is no additional information if you already have `M` and `N`, since you can just index `M` and `N` directly without storing the mapping, so you don't need `L` at all. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What is `N.shape` and `N.dtype`?

Comment: Another question on working with nested (2d 3d?) lists and whether numpy helps, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40289943/901925

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
zip(*[iter(([((row,col),N[row][col],M[row][col]) for row in range(2) for col in range(2)]))]*2)
```

result:

```
[(((0, 0), (0, 1), 1), ((0, 1), (1, 0), 2)),
 (((1, 0), (1, 1), 3), ((1, 1), (0, 0), 4))]
```

Comment: What difference does `np.array` make?  This just `list` code.

Comment: @hpaulj Well actually in my code I used list at last, but I forgot to copy it here. I just summarized my code. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: I wonder if the OP really has arrays.  `N` looks more like a nested list that `np.array` would turn into a 3d array.